# Different screen resolution showing good on tablet (1024x768), but bad on phone(800x480)

Tags: android, screen

I have a problem with my Android application. When I'm using my hp touchpad, which has a resolution of 1024x768 everything looks ok. However when I tested it on a 800x480 (Desire HD) this happened:
[image]

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
             />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonred"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

          <ImageButton
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:id="@+id/c101_image"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@drawable/cloud101"
            android:layout_weight=".20" />


         <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonred"
            android:text="@string/backspace"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="@string/b1"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDevide"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonblue"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="110sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMult"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonblue"
            android:text="X"
            android:textSize="110sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonblue"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="110sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutH5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonblue"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEq"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttongreen"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="110sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="@drawable/custombuttonblue"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="110sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've read about the problems of different screen sizes, but no matter if I use sp or dp, it still looks bad on the 800x480 screen. What should I do to get the font display correctly and the picture be nicely centered and not being closed in too tight ?

Comment: I can see that happening if the two devices have the same density, and it fits just right on the larger one. Can you take out the margins and center the text? Unfortunately size qualifiers are not available until android 3.2, or they might have helped.

Comment: just try this : i think it solves your problem : [link] http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You shouldn't user `sp` for views dimensions. User `dp` for dimensions of the views, and `sp` for text size.
Second: if you use `weightsum` and `layout_weight`, you don't need dimensions for views width, you give them 0dp value, and they will be drawn ok.

For example if you use this configuration:

```
 <ImageButton
       style="@style/ButtonText"
       android:id="@+id/c101_image"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType="centerInside"
       android:background="@drawable/cloud101"
       android:layout_weight=".20" />
```

your imageButton should be displayed correctly on all screens.
Use the same technique for all your views and it should solve your problem.

**Note**: Use a smaller font for your text :)

Good luck,
Arkde

Comment: I just need to find out a way now to make the font bigger on the tablet screen, on the tablet screen 70 sp is just too small again :(

Answer (score 1):

your textSize is too large for that device.

Make yourself a layout-normal folder inside your res directory and paste a copy of your layout in there. change the 110sp on your buttons down to something smaller. perhaps start trying with like 70sp or something. Test with different sizes until one looks good.

Also if you intend for your application to support small screens you'll need to make another copy of your layout file for them too.